# Multiple routes on google maps V3 javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to view different routes on the same map. I will load the routes from a file and put them in the two array "start" and "end".
calcRoute take the array start and the end as start and end of the route. I iterate this function (in this case two time) to create the two routes. But it is viewable only the last one. I would like to see all the routes that are inside the array.

```
var directionsDisplay;

var rendererOptions = {
            preserveViewport: true,
            draggable: false,
            suppressMarkers: true,
            polylineOptions: {
               map: map,
               strokeColor:'#FF0000',
               //strokeWidth: 3,
               strokeOpacity: 0.7}

};

var start = ['Trento, via belenzani 11', 'Trento, piazza duomo']
var end = ['Trento, via belenzani 50', 'Trento, piazza pasi']
var map;

function initialize() {


  var trento = new google.maps.LatLng(46.066712,11.119059);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom:12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: trento
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
  for (var i=0; i < 2; i++){
  calcRoute(start[i], end [i]);
}
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  }


function calcRoute(source,destination){
        // show route between the points
        directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        var request = {
            origin:source, 
            destination:destination,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) 
        {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) 
            {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

            }
        });

      }
```

Comment: Why the loop is not correct? My array is: position=[start1,end1,start2,end2,...]. calcRoute need (start1,end1) and then (start2, end2) so I need position k and k+1 and the next k+2 and k+3. That can be obtain by the loop that I have used. The definition of the calcRoute is at the end of the code posted:

Comment: This code before posting was working. It shows only the last postion. Now is not working. Mabye I have make some mistake in copy it. The for loop is not correct: I need for (var k; k<3; k++){calcRoute(percorso[k],percorso[k+1]); k++}

Comment: I have edited all the post: new code with two separated array one for the source and the other for the destination of the route. The structure is very similar to the previuos code, but this is working but display only the last route.

Comment: Find the solution: move the  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions); inside if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Display multiple routes on google map with waypoints and direction arrow
    ==============

Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yB4Tw.png )!


    ![In image u can see 2 routes with direction arrow][1]

     <style>
        html, body, #map_canvas { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100% }
        </style>


         <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

        <script>




          var directionsService;
          var stepDisplay;

          var position;
          var marker = [];
          var polyline = [];
          var poly2 = [];
          var poly = null;
          var startLocation = [];
          var endLocation = [];
          var timerHandle = [];




          var stops_data = [[ {"Geometry":{"Latitude":23.05242,"Longitude":72.53375}},

                              {"Geometry":{"Latitude":23.03007,"Longitude":72.59664}}

                            ] ,[ {"Geometry":{"Latitude":23.00959,"Longitude":72.56189}},
                                 {"Geometry":{"Latitude":23.05754,"Longitude":72.55302}}
                               ]];



          var a,z,b;

          var add;


          var speed = 0.000005, wait = 1;
          var infowindow = null;


           infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


          var myPano;   
          var panoClient;
          var nextPanoId;








              var directionsDisplay = [];

              directionsDisplay[0] = new window.google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                  suppressMarkers: true

                });


              directionsDisplay[1] = new window.google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
                  suppressMarkers: true

                });

              var map;
              var mapOptions = { center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.5584308, -70.8597732), zoom: 3,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };

              function initialize() 
              {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);


                directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();


             //   Setroute(locations[0],locations[1],directionsDisplay[0]);

               // Setroute(locations2[0],locations2[1],directionsDisplay[1]);


                Tour_startUp(stops_data[0]);

                window.tour.loadMap(map, directionsDisplay[0]);
               window.tour.fitBounds(stops_data[0],map);



                if (stops_data[0].length > 1)
                    window.tour.calcRoute(stops_data[0],directionsService, directionsDisplay[0]);



                Tour_startUp(stops_data[1]);
                window.tour.loadMap(map, directionsDisplay[1]);
                window.tour.calcRoute(stops_data[1],directionsService, directionsDisplay[1]);
                window.tour.fitBounds(stops_data[1],map);





              }




        function fx(o)
        {
          if(o && o.legs)
          {
            for(l=0;l<o.legs.length;l++)
            {
              var leg=o.legs[l];
              for(var s=0;s<leg.steps.length;++s)
              {
                var step=leg.steps[s],
                    a=(step.lat_lngs.length)?step.lat_lngs[0]:step.start_point,
                    z=(step.lat_lngs.length)?step.lat_lngs[1]:step.end_point,
                    dir=((Math.atan2(z.lng()-a.lng(),z.lat()-a.lat())*180)/Math.PI)+360,
                    ico=((dir-(dir%3))%120);
                    new google.maps.Marker({
                      position: a,
                      icon: new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/dir_'+ico+'.png',
                                                  new google.maps.Size(24,24),
                                                  new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                                                  new google.maps.Point(12,12)
                                                 ),
                map: map,
                title: Math.round((dir>360)?dir-360:dir)+'°'
              });

              }
            }
          }
        }


        function Tour_startUp(stops) {

            //  alert('first'+stops.length);     

            if (!window.tour) window.tour = {
                updateStops: function (newStops) {
                    stops = newStops;
                },


                // map: google map object
                // directionsDisplay: google directionsDisplay object (comes in empty)
                loadMap: function (map, dirdis) {
                    var myOptions = {
                        zoom: 15,
                        center: new window.google.maps.LatLng(51.507937, -0.076188), // default to London
                        mapTypeId: window.google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };
                    map.setOptions(myOptions);
                    dirdis.setMap(map);
                },
             fitBounds: function (stops_data,map) {
                    var bounds = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds();

                    // extend bounds for each record 
                    for( var x in stops_data) {
                        var myLatlng = new window.google.maps.LatLng(stops_data[x].Geometry.Latitude, stops_data[x].Geometry.Longitude);
                        bounds.extend(myLatlng);
                    }
                    map.fitBounds(bounds);
                },
                calcRoute: function (stops_new,directionsService, dirdis) {
                    var batches = [];
                    var itemsPerBatch = 10; // google API max = 10 - 1 start, 1 stop, and 8 waypoints
                    var itemsCounter = 0;
                    var wayptsExist = stops_new.length > 0;
                    var time= [];
                    while (wayptsExist) {
                        var subBatch = [];
                        var subitemsCounter = 0;

                       // alert('second'+stops_new.length);        
                //alert(stops_new[0].Geometry.Latitude +' ===== ' +stops_new[0].Geometry.Longitude);


                        for (var j = itemsCounter; j < stops_new.length; j++) {
                            subitemsCounter++;

                        //alert(stops[j].Geometry.Time);



                            subBatch.push({
                                location: new window.google.maps.LatLng(stops_new[j].Geometry.Latitude, stops_new[j].Geometry.Longitude),
                                stopover: true

                            });

                           //time.push(stops[j].Geometry.Time);

                            if (subitemsCounter == itemsPerBatch)
                                break;
                        }

                        itemsCounter += subitemsCounter;
                        batches.push(subBatch);
                        wayptsExist = itemsCounter < stops_new.length;
                        // If it runs again there are still points. Minus 1 before continuing to
                        // start up with end of previous tour leg
                        itemsCounter--;
                    }

                    // now we should have a 2 dimensional array with a list of a list of waypoints
                    var combinedResults;
                    var unsortedResults = [{}]; // to hold the counter and the results themselves as they come back, to later sort
                    var directionsResultsReturned = 0;




                    for (var k = 0; k < batches.length; k++) {
                        var lastIndex = batches[k].length - 1;
                        var start = batches[k][0].location;
                        var end = batches[k][lastIndex].location;

                        // trim first and last entry from array
                        var waypts = [];
                        waypts = batches[k];
                        waypts.splice(0, 1);
                        waypts.splice(waypts.length - 1, 1);

                        var request = 
                            {
                            origin: start,
                            destination: end,
                            waypoints: waypts,
                            travelMode: window.google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
                        };

                      //  alert('start'+start);

                     //   alert('end'+end);


                        (function (kk) {
                            directionsService.route(request, function (result, status) {



                                if (status == window.google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {


                                     fx(result.routes[0]);

                                     polyline[0] = new google.maps.Polyline({
                                         path: [],
                                         strokeColor: '#FFFF00',
                                         strokeWeight: 3
                                         });


                                     poly2[0] = new google.maps.Polyline({
                                         path: [],
                                         strokeColor: '#FFFF00',
                                         strokeWeight: 3
                                         });     


                                    var unsortedResult = { order: kk, result: result };
                                    unsortedResults.push(unsortedResult);

                                    directionsResultsReturned++;

                                    if (directionsResultsReturned == batches.length) // we've received all the results. put to map
                                    {
                                        // sort the returned values into their correct order
                                        unsortedResults.sort(function (a, b) { return parseFloat(a.order) - parseFloat(b.order); });
                                        var count = 0;
                                        for (var key in unsortedResults) {
                                            if (unsortedResults[key].result != null) {
                                                if (unsortedResults.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                                                    if (count == 0) // first results. new up the combinedResults object
                                                        combinedResults = unsortedResults[key].result;
                                                    else {
                                                        // only building up legs, overview_path, and bounds in my consolidated object. This is not a complete
                                                        // directionResults object, but enough to draw a path on the map, which is all I need
                                                        combinedResults.routes[0].legs = combinedResults.routes[0].legs.concat(unsortedResults[key].result.routes[0].legs);
                                                        combinedResults.routes[0].overview_path = combinedResults.routes[0].overview_path.concat(unsortedResults[key].result.routes[0].overview_path);

                                                        combinedResults.routes[0].bounds = combinedResults.routes[0].bounds.extend(unsortedResults[key].result.routes[0].bounds.getNorthEast());
                                                        combinedResults.routes[0].bounds = combinedResults.routes[0].bounds.extend(unsortedResults[key].result.routes[0].bounds.getSouthWest());
                                                    }
                                                    count++;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                        dirdis.setDirections(combinedResults);


                                        var legs = combinedResults.routes[0].legs;

                                        var path = combinedResults.routes[0].overview_path;

                                        //alert(path.length);

                                     //  alert(legs.length);

                                      //setRoutes(legs[0].start_location,legs[legs.length-1].end_location);



                                        for (var i=0; i < legs.length;i++)
                                            {
                                                  var markerletter = "A".charCodeAt(0);
                                                  markerletter += i;
                                          markerletter = String.fromCharCode(markerletter);

                                          if (i == 0) { 

                                            //marker[0] = createMarker2(legs[i].start_location,"start",legs[i].start_address,"green");
                                          }

                                          var steps = legs[i].steps;

                                        //  alert('arrival time : '+legs[i].arrival_time.text);

                                    //  var duration = steps.duration_in_traffic;

                                      // alert(duration.text);

                                          for (j=0;j<steps.length;j++) 
                                          {

                                              var nextSegment = steps[j].path;

                                              for (k=0;k<nextSegment.length;k++) 
                                                  {
                                                  polyline[0].getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
                                                  //bounds.extend(nextSegment[k]);
                                                     }
                                          }



                                        //  createMarker(directionsDisplay.getMap(),legs[i].start_location,"marker"+i,"some text for marker "+i+"<br>"+legs[i].start_address,markerletter);   
                                        }
                                            // Marker for start point 
                                        createMarker(dirdis.getMap(),legs[0].start_location,"marker"+0,"Start Point<br>"+legs[0].start_address,'A');


                                        var i=legs.length;
                                        var markerletter = "A".charCodeAt(0);
                                          markerletter += i;
                                        markerletter = String.fromCharCode(markerletter);

                                        // marker for End Point 
                                        createMarker(dirdis.getMap(),legs[legs.length-1].end_location,"marker"+i,"End Point <br>"+legs[legs.length-1].end_address,'B');

                                        polyline[0].setMap(map);

                                        //startAnimation(0);  
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        })(k);
                    }
                }
            };
        }


        var icons = new Array();
        icons["red"] = new google.maps.MarkerImage("mapIcons/marker_red.png",
              // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
              new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
              // The origin for this image is 0,0.
              new google.maps.Point(0,0),
              // The anchor for this image is at 9,34.
              new google.maps.Point(9, 34));



        function getMarkerImage(iconStr) {

        //alert(iconStr);

           if ((typeof(iconStr)=="undefined") || (iconStr==null)) { 
              iconStr = "red"; 
           }

        if(iconStr == 'A')
        {
           // for start point 


           if (!icons[iconStr]) {
              icons[iconStr] = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://www.google.com/mapfiles/dd-start.png",
              // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
              new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
              // The origin for this image is 0,0.
              new google.maps.Point(0,0),
              // The anchor for this image is at 6,20.
              new google.maps.Point(9, 34));
           } 

        }
        if (iconStr == 'B')
        {

            // for end point


            if (!icons[iconStr]) {
                  icons[iconStr] = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://www.google.com/mapfiles/dd-end.png",
                  // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
                  new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
                  // The origin for this image is 0,0.
                  new google.maps.Point(0,0),
                  // The anchor for this image is at 6,20.
                  new google.maps.Point(9, 34));
               } 


            }
        return icons[iconStr];
        }
          // Marker sizes are expressed as a Size of X,Y
          // where the origin of the image (0,0) is located
          // in the top left of the image.

          // Origins, anchor positions and coordinates of the marker
          // increase in the X direction to the right and in
          // the Y direction down.

          var iconImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('mapIcons/marker_red.png',
              // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
              new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
              // The origin for this image is 0,0.
              new google.maps.Point(0,0),
              // The anchor for this image is at 9,34.
              new google.maps.Point(9, 34));



          var iconShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://www.google.com/mapfiles/shadow50.png',
              // The shadow image is larger in the horizontal dimension
              // while the position and offset are the same as for the main image.
              new google.maps.Size(37, 34),
              new google.maps.Point(0,0),
              new google.maps.Point(9, 34));
              // Shapes define the clickable region of the icon.
              // The type defines an HTML &lt;area&gt; element 'poly' which
              // traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points. The final
              // coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first
              // coordinate.
          var iconShape = {
              coord: [9,0,6,1,4,2,2,4,0,8,0,12,1,14,2,16,5,19,7,23,8,26,9,30,9,34,11,34,11,30,12,26,13,24,14,21,16,18,18,16,20,12,20,8,18,4,16,2,15,1,13,0],
              type: 'poly'
          };


        function createMarker(map, latlng, label, html, color) {

        //alert(color);
        //  alert("createMarker("+latlng+","+label+","+html+","+color+")");


            var contentString = '<b>'+label+'</b><br>'+html;


        //    alert('creatMarker'+contentString);


            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                shadow: iconShadow,
                icon: getMarkerImage(color),
                shape: iconShape,
                title: label,
                zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
                });
                marker.myname = label;

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
                });


            return marker;
        }




              google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

        </script>

        <div id="map_canvas"></div>


      [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yB4Tw.png


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ld0j7.png
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, your for loop is not correct :

```
for (var k; k<0;k++){
  calcRoute(percorso[k], percorso[k+1]);
  k++;
}
```

[This might be useful for you](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript)

Cheers

Comment: What is the difference between your loop and OP's? -- The calcRoute function is there; just scroll down the code area.

Comment: My for loop is not different, I'm just showing him which for loop I'm talking about... Hadn't seen the calcRoute function was there so edited the answer