# Laravel Google Map

Tags: laravel, google-maps

Is there any way that I could show multiple directions on the map? Like from point A1 to point B1 then there is another direction where point A2 to point B2. Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Google map is inserted in a web-application using frontend javascript.

Laravel is php framework.
So these are not directly related. You might want to for example have the coordinates of each location stored in a database. In that case you might use a framework like Laravel to retrieve this data.

You would still have to place and configure the google map using javascript and html.

What you want to do is definitely possible. You can take a look at this question for more information.

[Multiple routes on google maps V3 javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682016/multiple-routes-on-google-maps-v3-javascript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Google has an extensive documentation which you can use to completely customise google map according to your wishes as a developer. If you want to find out more take a look at the documentation.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3.exp/